# Universal url scheme on iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript

I have an application built using NativeScript + Angular.

I have to share a link (universal url that would open my app). So taping on share button the application shares the url of a page inside. Then, the user which views the link and tap on it, should open directly with the (same) installed app.

This works fine on Android with the below configuration in manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.test.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

I'm using the SocialShare plugin to share the url:

```
share() {
    let url = this.router.url;
    SocialShare.shareUrl("http://www.test.com" + url, "http://www.test.com" + url);
 }
```

But on iOS the link just opens on Safari. I have already updated my info.plist file with configurations below

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>mytestapp</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>http://www.test.com</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

I tried using custom url scheme, something like 'test' on info.plist schema, and then I tried to share the following url: test://my_custom_routing, found it working.

It doesn't still if revert back to universal url scheme, What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS did not use to allow universal (http / https) based url schemes until v9.0. Most apps used [SmartBanners](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) Or would probably host a piece of JavaScript code that will redirect user to the app from Safari webpage.

Though iOS started supporting universal url schemes now, using them is not as easy as Android. It requires few more steps,

> Adding support for universal links is easy. There are three steps you
>   need to take:
>
> 1. Create an apple-app-site-association file that contains JSON data
>      about the URLs that your app can handle.
> 2. Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your HTTPS web server.
>      You can place the file at the root of your server or in the
>      .well-known subdirectory.
> 3. Prepare your app to handle universal links.
>
> You can test universal links on a device.

More detailed instructions can be found at the [official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).